# MIPS (MARS Simulator) - How to Store Compile-Time String Literals in the Heap

Tags: string, macros, mips

After learning what `.macro`s were in MARS, I decided to make a few to make my source code more readable.
An example of such a macro is my **str**ing **len**gth macro:

```
#Gets the length of a string from an address
#Result is in the second operand
#Doesn't count any null-terminators or newlines at the end of the input
#Call example:  strlen MyString,$s0
.macro strlen(%str, %i)
    la $t0,%str
    __strlen_loop:
        lb $t1,0($t0)
        #Exit the loop if this byte is null ('\0') or a newline ('\n')
        beqz $t1,__strlen_end
        beq $t1,'\n',__strlen_end
        inc $t0               #Increment-by-one macro
        j __strlen_loop
    __strlen_end:
    la $t1,%str
    sub %i,$t0,$t1
.end_macro
```

This macro works, but it relies on a predefined address in order to work (`%str`).
To try and remedy this problem, I created the following **str**ing **len**gth for **v**alue strings macro:

```
#Gets the string length of a value string (stores the string in .data)
#Call example:  strlen_v "Hello World!",$s0
.macro strlen_v(%str,%i)
    #Create a label for the string
    .data
    __strlen_v_label: .asciiz %str
    .text
    #Get the length
    strlen __strlen_v_label,%i
.end_macro
```

Unfortunately, there's another problem.  The second macro stores the value string in `.data`, which only has `0x30000` words' worth of space (address `0x10010000` to address `0x10040000`).
It would be preferable to store the value string on the **heap** instead, since it has much more space *and* I'll be able to manage the memory more efficiently.

---

Is storing a compile-time value string on the heap possible ***without*** using `.data`?  The only examples I've found were for user-input strings and strings already stored in `.data`, neither of which apply to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

> Is storing a compile-time value string on the heap possible without using .data?

Not really.  The heap is conceptually empty on program startup, by definition.  And, also by definition, string literals are constants initialized in the data section.  You can only allocate heap space at runtime, not at compile time; so, at runtime you can allocate heap space and move strings from literals data into heap...

---

However, let's note that MARS and QtSPIM allow an argument to `.data`, which is the location where to place subsequent content.  For example, we can do `.data 0x10040000`, which will cause subsequent string literals to be place there, for example.  However, this will interfere with normal heap operation in that your first sbrk syscall will still return `0x10040000`, the memory occupied by string literals placed there using `.data 0x10040000`, as the sbrk syscall isn't aware of the directive.

---

Defining string length as a function instead of a macro will probably be more of what you want in the long term:

- you can determine the length of a string literal, local string, or heap-based string,
- your register conventions will fall into the normal calling convention (not sure there even is a register convention for macros),
- you will separate the concerns of string literal declaration from string length operation.